# Azure Synapse Analytics - CI/CD workspace and infrastructure - Design question

Tags: azure, project, azure-synapse, cicd

I have an Azure Repos project with IaC code and ci/cd yaml pipelines to set up Azure Synapse infrastructure. Can you recommend what is right approach when I integrate the workspace to connect to git? Should I create a new project in Azure Repos for the Synapse artifacts or should I use the same repository as the infrastructure project?

I will be setting up ci/cd pipelines to deploy the azure synapse artifacts as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75060840/synapse-pipeline-import-resource-from-git/75062575#75062575) an answer to a similar question I posted:

> You'll want to follow [Microsoft's guide on CI/CD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery) with Synapse. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoylhR5VjNY) is a great walkthrough video for the process.

> Work in your development environment and commit to your collaboration branch.
> A pipeline triggers off of your workspace_publish branch, releasing your code to your next environment (preferably with an approval gate)
> Continue releasing the same code to higher environments, again with approval gates.
> For Azure DevOps, you can use variable groups to parameterize your pipeline. Also make sure to read through the custom parameters section on that link to parameterize parts of the template that are not parameterized by default.