# Synapse pipeline import resource from git

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have a situation here where I import resources from my Azure DevOps Git repository DEV to TEST, I want DEV code to be independent of TEST and not commit my changes back to the repository.

[image]

After I import the repository to TEST I made changes to the SQL database connection string in the copy activity source and sink in TEST and had to commit the changes for the debug to run and the triggers I have setup for the pipelines don't run in TEST as per the schedule and fail in DEV because of the changes I did in TEST.

When move the pipelines and underlying objects to different environments, How do I make all the environments independent once I import repository? Is there a way to copy from the repository to the Synapse live mode to accomplish this?

***OR*** How would I automate deployment of Synapse pipelines? Is it using ARM or Bicep Template?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to follow [Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery) on CI/CD with Synapse. [This](https://youtu.be/CoylhR5VjNY) is a great walkthrough video for the process.

The flow is:

- Work in your development environment and commit to your collaboration branch.
- A pipeline triggers off of your workspace_publish branch, releasing your code to your next environment (preferably with an approval gate)
- Continue releasing the same code to higher environments, again with approval gates.

For Azure DevOps, you can use [variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to parameterize your pipeline. Also make sure to read through the custom parameters section on that link to parameterize parts of the template that are not parameterized by default.